# Grey out item in Highcharts legend

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Is there a way to make an item in a Highcharts legend inactive (i.e. greyed out) at runtime? The item needs to be greyed out independently of whether the the series on the chart is visible or not. The pseudo code would look something like `item[0].inactive`.

I have found options to destroy the item on the legend, but that is not what I am trying to do.

Comment: I've got a feeling that all you'd need to do is find the element that needs to be greyed out, and then apply some CSS styling to it.

Comment: Hello Alex :-) That did cross my mind ... but sound a bit like a hack. What happens for example if I then want to enable it? I'd need to assign a new colour to it, which sounds like a pain in the proverbial. Am looking for an easier fix!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you knew the element (let's call it `div#legend`), then you could create custom CSS classes for it.  For instance:

```
.legendDisabled {
    background-color: #FFFFFF
}

.legendEnabled {
    background-color: #00FF00
}
```

Then you could use jQuery selectors to toggle between these classes when you need to grey out the legend or "enable" the legend, using [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/):

```
$("div#legend").toggleClass("legendDisabled");
$("div#legend").toggleClass("legendEnabled");
```